# MS Access - summing a field to be used in another field

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I am trying to use the sum of one field and use it to compare with another field in the same query. The goal of this is to sum up the total requirement for each job component then subtract it from that item's inventory. I tried both doing this in the same query and also making a separate query to sum up the Req field and then do the calculation (Transfer: Req-Inventory) but I keep getting errors about aggregate functions not being included.

Note - I removed the Transfer QTY field from both queries because I tried it in both and it doesn't work. I am not sure where/how to write it in.

**This is the main query**

```
SELECT dbo_job.whse, dbo_jobmatl.item, ((IIf([qty_released]-[qty_complete]<0,0,[qty_released]-[qty_complete]))*[matl_qty]) AS Req, dbo_item.product_code
FROM dbo_item INNER JOIN (qry_BENWhseInventory INNER JOIN (dbo_job INNER JOIN dbo_jobmatl ON (dbo_job.suffix = dbo_jobmatl.suffix) AND (dbo_job.job = dbo_jobmatl.job)) ON qry_BENWhseInventory.Item = dbo_jobmatl.Item) ON dbo_item.item = dbo_jobmatl.item
WHERE (((dbo_item.product_code) Not Like "RM-CANDY" And (dbo_item.product_code) Not Like "FG - CLRM") AND ((dbo_job.job) Not Like "*R0*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "WT*" And (dbo_job.job) Not Like "BM*") AND ((dbo_job.job_date)>=[Forms]![MainForm]![Text0] And (dbo_job.job_date)<=Nz([Forms]![MainForm]![Text3],[Forms]![MainForm]![Text0])) AND ((dbo_job.item) Not Like "Indirect"))
ORDER BY dbo_job.job, dbo_job.suffix, dbo_job.whse;
```

**This is the separate query attempt**

```
SELECT qry_TransferSimple.item, Sum([Req]) AS sum_Req
FROM qry_BENWhseInventory INNER JOIN qry_TransferSimple ON qry_BENWhseInventory.item = qry_TransferSimple.item
GROUP BY qry_TransferSimple.item, Sum([Req]);
```

**This is a simplified view of the data I am working with**

```
Job:   Item:     Req:     Inventory:     
1       A        100       100
2       B        200       200
3       A        300       100
4       C        400       300  
5       B        500       200
```

**This is what I want the outcome to be**

```
Item:     Transfer QTY:
A          300
B          500
C          100
```

Comment: If *Transfer QTY* is supposed to be *Req* minus *Inventory*, why do you want 300 instead of 200 for the cumulative *A* value?  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @HansUp the thing is that if an item in duplicated in this table (as in the case of A), the inventory for that item is also duplicated. There is only 1 instance of inventory for A - qty: 100. You don't sum up the inventory amounts. However, you **do** sum up the requirements because they are the different amounts needed for different jobs.

Comment: Aha! In that case what is the benefit of storing repeated *Inventory* values?

Comment: The table is set up that way because the job is the unique identifier. I'm not sure why this table was created this way in my company's database. Assuming they had this divided into job information in one table and inventory in another, would that help me to set up my query? I can probably ask my IT admin to create a View for me...

Comment: They may actually have the data normalized already, but present it unnormalized for the convenience of "normal" users.  That kind of thing happens often.  If you're importing it into your Access db, you can store normalized.  Otherwise you can create an Access query to retrieve the normalized inventory data.  Then start with `SELECT y.Item, Sum(y.Req) AS SumOfReq FROM YourTable AS y GROUP BY y.Item`, join that to inventory (table or query) on *Item* and then use `(SumOfReq - Inventory) AS [Transfer QTY]`

Comment: But if you have a cooperative DBA, rely of his or her guidance.  That would be ideal.